# M320 Grenade Launcher: Under-slung vs. Standalone

Tags: battlefield-3

What is the difference between having the M320 Grenade Launcher attached to your rifle and having it as a standalone weapon?

Is it worth giving up an attachment (like the forward grip) to have it under-slung?

Comment: From what I'm reading (Correct me if I'm wrong; I haven't played enough beta to unlock it) you can have it as a gadget and use an attachment like a grip or as an attachment and use a gadget like a medkit. In that case, it depends on which is more valuable; the gadget or the attachment. Probably depends a lot on your style of play.

Comment: @SSumner No, how it works is: it's always a gadget that replaces your med-pack (gadget 1), and it's a standalone weapon. Unless that is, you use the "underslung rail" primary attachment, in which case it will become an underslung weapon, however only some rifles have the underslung rail attachment.

Comment: So even if you use it as an attachment, it still replaces your med-pack? If so, yeah, I can see no advantage to using it as an attachment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use underslung attachments in Battlefield 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34010/how-can-i-use-underslung-attachments-in-battlefield-3)

Comment: @Bora It's not a duplicate in any way, I know exactly how to use my underslung attachment, I'm just asking whether or not it's worth it, as the stats seemed the same (and they are).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not underslung:**

- 1 second switch time

  3 second reload time

**Underslung**

- 1 second switch time

  3 second reload time

  You have to give up bipod or foregrip

Everyone has to decide for themselves. But personally I think using it underslung is a joke.

Comment: I'll probably wait until actual release to see if this still holds up before I accept it, but I'm actually very disappointed in this, from my own testing I figured having it as a weapon was way better, but I was hoping someone would find some advantage of having it underslung, or at least some disadvantage of having it stand alone.

Comment: per http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAfQNX14rCY underslung is *supposed* to be faster to deploy. We'll have to wait to see in the final this Oct 25th.

Comment: Ok, I just did some testing using recorded video and playing them back side by side, and they're exactly the same even in release, so I'll be accepting this answer, but editing it a bit.

Comment: @MrSmooth, could you link to your video? I agree it does seem broken as is. Maybe we could get the video in front of a community manager or developer.

Comment: @robertpateii I never actually rendered the video, and I no longer have the footage, I just put the videos side by side in the the video editor without actually making a video.

Answer (score 1):

The M320 is a stand-alone grenade launcher in the "gadget 1" slot. Medics, for instance, must give up their med-kit in order to use an M320. I've seen a lot of questions about this related to the underslung rail. The underslung rail is supposed to reduce the time it takes you to switch to the M320. Even though the underslung rail supposedly mounts the grenade launch under the barrel of an assault rifle, it ***still*** takes up your gadget slot- so you must still give up the med-kit to use the M320.

Answer (score 1):

There is a video on youtube by user [Darius822](http://www.youtube.com/user/Darius822) that measures the switching times to and from the **M320** grenade launcher and the **M416** assault rifle:

According to the video's description, he used macros to trigger the weapon change to make sure the timings weren't affected by human errors.

### Results

**Underbarrel:**

```
Switching to: 18 frames = 0.6sec
Switching from: 16 frames = 0.53sec
```

**Separate:**

```
Switching to: 17 frames = 0.57sec
Switching from: 24 frames = 0.8sec
```

**Conclusion**

So it seems there is a small performance gain by having it mounted underslung when switching from it back to the assault rifle (*50% faster*). That *could* mean surviving a sudden encounter with an enemy...